# Messages sent to an active conversation are not immediately displayed in MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, http, botframework, chatbot

I send a message from a bot to addressed to a user **on webchat** with his active conversation id, using BotConnector (Messages.SendMessage method)

The problem is that the message is only displayed when the user messages the bot again.

Example: Bot sends "Testing message"

User sees nothing

User sends bot "Hello"

Response:

"Testing message"

"Hi! I'm a bot"

Note: Here, "Hi! I'm a bot" is what the bot would have responded for "Hello"

Comment: Do you have the same problems if you follow the [Get Started](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted) page?

Comment: Not at all. My bot functions normally otherwise - right now, I'm trying to use the SendMessage method, which is where the problem occurs.

Comment: What channel is this happening on?

Comment: @Lars It's happening for webchat channel

Comment: Same here! it shows only after a subsequent message is sent. I'm on V1, using node SDK